# XSLT - Get nodes by checking content

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <p>  first sentence</p>
    <p>second sentence</p>
    <p>     third sentence</p>
</doc>
```

I need to get `<p>` nodes which have space at the first. in this case I need to get first and third `<p>` nodes.

can you suggest a method how can I do this in xslt?

Comment: have you tried starts-with() function of xslt??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out the following

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(.,' ')">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Do note I haven't mentioned stylesheet element in my answer.